# how to find continued fractions with terms less than or equal to -2?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

How can one find a continued fraction with all the terms less than or equal to -2? meaning that $x=[a_0,a_1,...,a_n]$ with $a_i\leq -2$.

Comment: The same way as a normal continued fraction.

Comment: thanks for the clear extensive answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sorry for providing an answer which might sound dumb like that, but I really don't see what problems could arise when allowing non-positive partial quotients.

Comment: I should apologize for being sarcastic. It is not clear how to make all terms less than or equal to negative two. For instance for $3/2=[1,2]$ but to  find an expansion $3/2=[a_0,a_1,...,a_n]$ with $a_i \leq -2$ doesn't seem obvious to me now.

Comment: Ah, I think part of fault is on my side, because I have misunderstood the question - I thought you were asking for a way of finding a value of a continued fraction. With the question as it stands now, I don't think it's always possible. I believe the continued fraction like that is always less than $-1$.